# Java program runs fine in Eclipse but not as a .jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, executable-jar

I've got an issue with my .jar file.  It runs fine in Eclipse but as soon as I export it, it won't open.  I've checked the manifest file and it looks like it's okay.

I've tried exporting it as a runnable jar, as well as just using the jar builder.  Nothing worked.

I've tried to run it in command prompt and it says it can't access the jar file... I've searched around a while on here and haven't found an answer yet.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  The only thing I can think of is I'm not getting my images correctly.

I'm using .png files for the program's sprites and here's an example of how I get them for my program.

This code begins the building of a level from a .png file.

```
public class SpawnLevel extends Level{

public SpawnLevel(String path) {
    super(path);
}

protected void loadLevel(String path){
    try{
        System.out.println("classpath is: " + System.getProperty("java.class.path"));
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(SpawnLevel.class.getResource(path));
        int w = width = image.getWidth();
        int h = height= image.getHeight();
        tiles = new int[w*h];
        image.getRGB(0,0,w,h,tiles,0,w);
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("EXEPTION FOUND!!!  Could not load the level file!");
    }
}

protected void generateLevel(){
    System.out.println("Tiles: " + tiles[0]);
}

}
```

I've made one other .jar before for another program and didn't have a problem.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

If it helps, I used this code to display the resource folder path information.

```
System.out.println("classpath is: " + System.getProperty("java.class.path"));
```

Here's what my current path for my resources folder looks like.  Before I export it from eclipse.

```
    classpath is: C:\Users\name\workspace\Rpg_Game\bin;C:\Users\name\workspace\Rpg_Game\res
```

After I export to .jar

```
    classpath is: 2ndGameTest.jar
```

Comment: try SpawnLevel.class.getResourceAs(path) and what the path is or can you attach the error log?

Comment: how you are running the jar file? where is your main class?

Comment: @andy I changed my code to SpawnLevel.class.getResourceAsStream(path) and now when I run it through command prompt, it's giving me exceptions that say imageIo.read(Unknown Source).

Comment: This is usually either the path string being wrong or the images not being included in the jar.

Comment: @greg-449 My images are in the project folder and appear when I export the project.  I'm looking in "configure Build Path" on my project.  What should I see if the build path's correct?  I currently see the src, system Library, and my resource folder.

Comment: I meant the path you give to `getResource` or `getResourceAsStream`.

Comment: Sorry about that, the code with the path I used for the level's image is: BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(SpawnLevel.class.getResourceAsStream("/levels/Level1.png")).  Similarly, an example for the actual game graphics it's BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(SpriteSheet.class.getResourceAsStream("/textures/sheets/InsertSpriteheetNameHere"));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your images are in your `resources` package in the `src` The path you should be using for `getResource()` is something like

```
class.getResource("/resources/levels/level1.png")
```

---

**UPDATE** with test program

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class TestImage {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Image image = ImageIO.read(TestImage.class.getResource("/resources/images/image.png"));
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image);
        JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, label);
    }
}
```

Comment: My resources folder is outside of my src.  I tried putting resources in the src folder and tweaking my code, but it had the same result; it works fine in eclipse but not as a jar.

Comment: Ok I posted a test program. Open a new project, create the resources/images in the src and put the image in the images. Use this as a test program. package it in the jar and see if you see the image. Let me know. If it works, then you know there's something wrong with your program.

Comment: the test program worked when I ran it as a jar, so it is a problem with my code somewhere.  Any tips on where to look next?

Comment: The exception occurs when you call `loadLevel`? Also, what exactly are you passing at the `path` to the method, if that is where the problem is.

Comment: Everything runs fine in eclipse.  But when I make a jar file and try to run it through command prompt, it gives me a null error when it tries to read any of my images.  So the problem seems to occur when it calls an image, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: The first thing you need to do is make sure your image directories are in the `resource`, which is in the `src`. Next you _have_ to make sure at _all_ paths you are using for `getResources` are in the format `"/resources/imagedir/image.png"`. That's all I can really suggest right now. Other that that, I may need to see more code, maybe a small runnable program.

Comment: The reason it runs fine in eclipse and not the jar is because they are two different environments. To sync them, you need to read the resources from the class path. The images out side the src are not resources on the class path, and may not get transfered to the jar. That's why you want all your application resources in the src somewhere. When it gets built, the files in the src get built to bin, which is the classpath root, as you say in your test print

Comment: Thanks for your help.  After looking at my paths and using your ImageTest program, I discovered that my paths simply all had to be the correct case to load properly in my jar file.